# Force Youtube Link to Open in App on Android/iOS

Tags: javascript, android, html, ios, youtube

I have a bunch of Youtube links on my mobile web page. When the user clicks on one of these links, I want the video to open in the Youtube app. Is there a way to achieve this via Javascript, and if there is can I detect if they do not have the Youtube app so I can provide a fallback?

Answer (score 0):

> Unlike some schemes, YouTube URLs do not start with a “youtube” scheme identifier. Instead, they are specified as regular http links but are targeted at the YouTube server.

[Apple URL Scheme Reference - YouTube Links](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/YouTubeLinks/YouTubeLinks.html)

The default behavior of the YouTube URL scheme is to open any YouTube video 
links in the YouTube app.  If the user does not have the app installed, Safari will load YouTube's mobile site.

Comment: What about Android devices? Is there a special scheme for those?